# Convert image buffer to base64

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am resizing base64 image with jimp:

```
   const buffer = Buffer.from(Photo, 'base64');
   const { mime } = fileType(buffer);
   const photoBuffer = await jimp.read(buffer);

   const res = await photoBuffer.cover(10, 10)
       .quality(30).getBufferAsync(mime);
```

now I need to conver 'res' buffer back to base64.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `toString` method of `Buffer` like this:

```
const resInBase64 = res.toString('base64')
```